# Printing to USB Printers from FoxPro 2.6

Tags: usb, foxpro

I have an application in foxpro on my XP machine that needs to print to a USB printer. I found this post which was helpful to all but not me. May be I am messing somewhere .

When I add **NET USE LPT1: \MYCOMPUTERNAME\MYPRINTERNAME** to the logon script, I get the unrecognized or wrong command error. What should be the correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the semicolon after LPT1, and use double backslash before 'mycomputername'.

```
net use lpt1 \\mycomputername\myprintername
```

Also bear in mind that even this approach does not always work - it is very possible that you will be unable to ever get it to work and will have to resort to a software solution like [dos2usb](http://www.dos2usb.com/).